# Is array dependence on previous terms considered recursive?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

For example, take the case of Fibonacci number to calculate nth number you require `n-1` and `n-2` term.

If I do it with bottom up approach, is it recursion as `f(n)` depends on `f(n-1)`?

Comment: It's recursive with memoization, I think.

Answer (score 2):

There are several slightly different meanings to the term "recursive":

- The definition of Fibonacci sequence is [*recurrent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). This is property of the definition, no matter how you implement it.
- The function to calculate it is [*totally recursive*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_recursive_function), i.e. computable.
- The implementation of the function is recursive if it actually calls itself. If you create the array manually and convert the recursion to a loop, it usually is *not* called recursive.

The bottom-up approach is (without unnecessarily wasting space for n values when last two is all that's required):

```
def fib(n):
   f_2, f_1 = 0, 1
   for _ in xrange(1, n):
       f_2, f_1 = f_1, f_2 + f_1
   return f_1
```

and that's *not recursive*.

However any loop can be rewritten as recursive, which would look like:

```
def fib(n):
   def f(n, f_2, f_1):
      if n == 1:
         return f_1
      else:
         return f(n, f_1, f_2 + f_1)
   return f(n, 0, 1)
```

It's getting somewhat convoluted by now though, but in functional languages (like Haskell) and mostly functional ones (like Lisp/Scheme) it would probably be the more natural definition. And in those languages with tail-recursion optimization (like Haskell or Scheme) it is just as efficient.

Comment: To confuse matters even more: in a language with Proper Tail Calls, your latter procedure definition is recursive (or more precisely, *tail-recursive*), but *calling* it yields an iterative process.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Actually I initially had another version that was recursive, but not tail-recursive, but that would not qualify as bottom-up approach. The accumulator tail-recursive transformation of the loop fits that better. And while editing the note about tail-recursion slipped through the crack.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider it "recursion" if you call a function calls itself.

Something like this:

```
f(n) {
   ....
   return f(n-2) + f(n-1);
}
```

You do the same thing with a loop and it wouldn't be recursion

```
f(n) {
  .....
  for ( i =2 ; i< n ;i++) 
     arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2]
}
```